# How do I detect if X and Z position is intersecting a certain mesh (not using mouse)? - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

**Background of Question**

I am working on a game that is a mix between Europa Universalis 4 and Age of Empires 3. The game is made in ***JavaScript*** and utilizes ***Three.js (r109)*** library. As of right now I have made randomly generated low-poly terrain with trees and reflective water. In the beginning I want the game to spawn a Navy, represented by a galleon **(in screenshot below)**. I want to make it so when its called to spawn, it will pick a random location within the bounds of the water. The water mesh is represented by a semi-opaque **plane** spanning the size of the map- with a `THREE.Reflector` object underneath it. The terrain is also a **plane** but has been altered using a ***SimplexNoise*** heightmap.

[image]

**The Question**

*How do I detect if an **x** and **z** position intersects with the water mesh and **not** the terrain mesh?* `THREE.Raycaster` seems to be useful for what I am trying to do, but I wan't to know if there is a better solution. If using  `THREE.Raycaster` is the best option, how would I go about implementing it for this purpose? Should I make an individual `THREE.Raycaster` for every object I am doing this with? **Keep in mind I'm not placing this object with the mouse, I want to place it with a method that checks the position as stated above.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to give specific advice without knowing anything at all about your code, but it sounds like all you need to do is create a collision list for your valid water surfaces and then check that when you want to spawn something.

A very simple jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p1eck3us/).  It creates a "land" mesh (green) and a "water" mesh (blue), adds the "water" mesh to a variable called **collisionList**.  It then calls a **spawn** function for coordinates diagonally across both surfaces.  The function uses a raycaster to check if the coordinates are over the "water" mesh and spawns a red cube if it is.

Here's the code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var camera = null, land = null, water = null, renderer = null, lights;
    var collisionList;
    var d, n, scene = null, animID;

    n = document.getElementById('canvas');

    function load() {
            var height = 600, width = 800;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, width/height, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.set(0, 0, -10);

            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            scene.add(camera);

            lights = [];
            lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
            lights[1] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
            lights[2] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
            lights[0].position.set(0, 200, 0);
            lights[1].position.set(100, 200, 100);
            lights[2].position.set(-100, -200, -100);
            scene.add(lights[0]);
            scene.add(lights[1]);
            scene.add(lights[2]);

            water = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(7, 7, 10),
                    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                            color:  0x0000ff,
                            side:   THREE.DoubleSide,
                    }));
            water.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            scene.add(water);

            land = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(12, 12, 10),
                    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                            color:  0x00ff00,
                            side:   THREE.DoubleSide,
                    }));
            land.position.set(0, 0, 1);
            scene.add(land);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            n.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            collisionList = [ water ];

            for(var i = -6; i < 6; i++)
                    spawn(i);
            
            animate();
    }
    function spawn(x) {
            var dir, intersect, mesh, ray, v;

            v = new THREE.Vector3(x, x, -1);
            dir = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
            ray = new THREE.Raycaster(v, dir.normalize(), 0, 100);
            intersect = ray.intersectObjects(collisionList);
            if(intersect.length <= 0)
                    return;
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 }));
            mesh.position.set(x, x, 0);
            scene.add(mesh);
    }
    function animate() {
            if(!scene) return;
            animID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
            update();
    }
    function render() {
            if(!scene || !camera || !renderer) return;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    function update() {
            if(!scene || !camera) return;
    }
    
    load();
```

As for whether this is a smart way to do it, that really depends on the design of the rest of your game.

If your world is procgen then it may be more efficient/less error prone to generate the spawn points (and any other "functional" parts of the world) first and use that to generate the geography instead of the other way around.

Comment: I have made the elements of your Fiddle work for my game. Perfect solution to what I was asking for. Sorry for not giving my code I just didn't think it would be useful due to what I am asking being rather general. But still, you have given me the answer and solution I needed.